# How to ignore empty values in array when checking for duplicates - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, compare

In Javascript, I am testing two arrays to check for duplicates. I found a nice simple way to do this in ES6

```js
function hasDuplicates(MyArray) {
    return new Set(MyArray).size !== MyArray.length;
      }
```

However, I want it to ignore empty values in the array, as it counts empty values as a duplicate.

My array looks like this: ["name 0", "name", "name 2", "", ""]

How can I do this?

Comment: please share the two array and also please show how this function is called

Comment: note that if `MyArray` is an Array of `Objects`, it will check if the reference of the objects are same, not the data itself

Comment: what about u create a new array after removing empty values and then check the length with Set size

Comment: @brk added the array.

Comment: @elvis_ferns i'll try that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line before `return` statement

```
var tmpArray = MyArray.filter( s => (s || !isNaN(s)) && String(s).length > 0 );
```

And use this array in return statement

```
return new Set( tmpArray ).size !== tmpArray.length;
```

Or just extend the same line to check for duplicates

```
return MyArray.filter( ( s, i, arr ) => 
         (s || !isNaN(s)) && String(s).length > 0 
           && arr.indexOf( s, i + 1 ) != -1 ).length > 0;
```

This will return `true` if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the dupe array as result, this is my solution to your problem:

```
let data = ["101", "", "", "666"];
let compData = ["", "", "666", "101"];
var result = data.filter((value) => {
    if(value !="" && compData.indexOf(value) > -1)
        return value;
})
```

outputs:

```
["101", "666"]
```